# Why am I facing this?

Tags: php, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Why am I facing this problem "#1072 - Key column 'profile_id' doesn't exist in table" while importing the database after adding a foreign key named 'profile_id' at table 'user_individual' table?

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.2.0.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jun 27, 2013 at 05:48 AM
-- Server version: 5.1.37
-- PHP Version: 5.3.0

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `event_management`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `profile_company`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profile_company` (
  `profile_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `name_business_profile` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `day` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `month` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `year` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `business_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `house_no` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `road_no` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `area_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `area_code` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `district` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `division` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `time_zone` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `phone_office` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `phone_outlet` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `phone_mobile` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `other_email_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `other_email_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `other_email_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `website_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `website_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `website_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `organization_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `organization_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `organization_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nonprofit_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nonprofit_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nonprofit_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `currency_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `currency_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `currency_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `security_code_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `security_code_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `security_code_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`profile_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `profile_company`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `profile_individual`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profile_individual` (
  `profile_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `name_business_profile` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `day` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `month` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `year` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `regilion` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `national_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `business_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `house_no` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `road_no` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `area_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `area_code` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `district` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `division` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `time_zone` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `phone_office` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `phone_home` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `phone_mobile` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `other_email_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `other_email_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `other_email_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `website_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `website_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `website_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `organization_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `organization_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `organization_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nonprofit_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nonprofit_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nonprofit_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `security_code_1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `security_code_2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `security_code_3` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`profile_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `profile_individual`
--

INSERT INTO `profile_individual` (`profile_id`, `name_business_profile`, `gender`, `day`, `month`, `year`, `regilion`, `nationality`, `national_id`, `business_id`, `house_no`, `road_no`, `area_name`, `area_code`, `district`, `division`, `country`, `country_code`, `time_zone`, `phone_office`, `phone_home`, `phone_mobile`, `other_email_1`, `other_email_2`, `other_email_3`, `website_1`, `website_2`, `website_3`, `organization_1`, `organization_2`, `organization_3`, `nonprofit_1`, `nonprofit_2`, `nonprofit_3`, `currency`, `security_code_1`, `security_code_2`, `security_code_3`, `image`) VALUES
('C091219', 'Illeens Event Solution', 'female', '4', '11', '1990', 'Islam', 'Bangladeshi', 'N12345', 'B67890', '59', '1', 'Jamal Khan', '8420', 'Chittagong', 'Chittagong', 'Bangladesh', '50', '(GMT +6:00) Almaty, Dhaka, Colombo', '01819300331', '01617766640', '01670303979', 'illeen@yahoo.com', 'illeen@gmail.com', 'illeen@hotmail.com', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'Illeens Boutique', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'Taka', '12345', '67890', '77777', 'Illeen.jpg'),
('C091222', 'Event Solution By Mahin', 'female', '27', '10', '1989', 'Islam', 'Bangladeshi', 'N67890', 'B12345', '48', '1', 'Jamal Khan', '8421', 'Chittagong', 'Chittagong', 'Bangladesh', '50', '6', '01813456789', 'None', 'None', 'mahin@live.com', 'None', 'None', 'www.facebook.com/mahin', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'Taka', 'abcde', 'efghi', 'ijklm', 'Mahin.jpg');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user_company`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_company` (
  `company_name` text NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email_address`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user_company`
--

INSERT INTO `user_company` (`company_name`, `email_address`, `phone`, `user_name`, `password`) VALUES
('Ctg Events', 'ctgevents@yahoo.com', '+8801234567890', '58eef294b54847752782276ffad32967', '58eef294b54847752782276ffad32967'),
('Cliczo Photography', 'cliczo@yahoo.com', '+8801345762398', '67ebd15ec49280cb32f627178e16c0e2', '67ebd15ec49280cb32f627178e16c0e2'),
('Suhanas Mehendi', 'suhana@yahoo.com', '+88031631234', 'a356446b79ecda0ad10c339db195262e', 'a356446b79ecda0ad10c339db195262e');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user_individual`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_individual` (
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email_address`),
  KEY `profile_id`(`profile_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user_individual`
--

INSERT INTO `user_individual` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email_address`, `phone`, `user_name`, `password`) VALUES
('Ajfar', 'Illeen', 'illeen@live.com', '+8801670303979', '44aee4495409c9c85f665c448df2575b', '44aee4495409c9c85f665c448df2575b'),
('Ajfar', 'Illeen', 'illeen@yahoo.com', '+8801670303979', '44aee4495409c9c85f665c448df2575b', '44aee4495409c9c85f665c448df2575b'),
('Mahin', 'Islam', 'mahin@yahoo.com', '+8801671804138', '74d5ee8d9e9c1659bf3ee0c3b9838adb', '74d5ee8d9e9c1659bf3ee0c3b9838adb');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: You are trying to add an index (`KEY`) on `(profile_id)` but there is no such column (`profile_id`) in the table!

Comment: Unrelated to the problem but you have no foreign keys in the database anyway. You have some indexes but no foreign keys at all. You would need InnoDB engine for that, MyISAM has so foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[proper syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)** to define a FK constraint.

Assuming that `user_individual` references `profile_individual` your statement should look like

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_individual` (
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `profile_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL, -- < you have to have an FK column
  PRIMARY KEY (`email_address`),  
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY fk_profile_id (`profile_id`) 
  REFERENCES profile_individual(`profile_id`) -- < you have to define an FK constraint that references to PK
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e26d8)** demo.

Comment: Thank you so much... :) I missed it... :/

Comment: You can't define FK constraints with MyISAM tables.